# alloy beginner's concept

Tags: alloy

I'm quite new to alloy and currently reading the tutorials at mit. I got a little stuck in the logic of things. A very basic thing i'm trying to do is below.

- a person can only do at most 1 task
- a task can be done at most by 1 person
- a person can only do what s/he is able to

When i run the following, everyone has the same skills(all skills) and every task requires the same skills (all again). The people at least get assigned 1 task each but they get the same task sometimes.

thanks in advance

```
some sig Skills{ }


some sig Person  {
 has:  some Skills, 
 assigned: lone Task
 }

some sig Task
 {  
 requires: some Skills
 }
 {
// everyone must have the required task skills for assignment
 all p:Person | p.has= requires
 }

pred Valid ()
 {  
//everyone must be assigned to single task
  all p:Person | lone t:Task| p.assigned in t
// no one can have the same task
  no p1:Person , p2:Person | p1.assigned not in p2.assigned
 }

run Valid
```

Comment: changing predicament to only `no p1:Person| all p2:Person | p1.assigned in p2.assigned` seemed to work better then the previous but still has the same problem on some instances. Also why is that even if there are more than 1 skills, all person and task relations go to the same skill every time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of things that are incorrect in your model.

> - *a person can only do at most 1 task*

To implement this, the `lone` multiplicity modifier for the `assigned` field in the `Person` signature is sufficient.  If you want every person to have exactly one task assigned, you can change `lone` to `one`.

> - *a task can be done at most by 1 person*

Your constraint in the `Valid` predicate is wrong because instead of `p1.assigned not in p2.assigned` you should write `p1.assigned = p2.assigned` in order to say that there are no two persons that have the same task assigned.  Additionally you should add a constraint that ensures that `p1 != p2`.  Alternatively, you could write `all p1, p2: Person | p1 != p2 implies p1.assigned != p2.assigned`.  Finally, to avoid having to write `p1 != p2` in the quantifier body, you can use the `disj` keyword to say, e.g., `no disj p1, p2: Person | p1.assigned = p2.assigned`, or `all disj p1, p2: Person | p1.assigned != p2.assigned`.

> - *a person can only do what s/he is able to*

Your constraint in the appended facts section of the `Task` signature is wrong because it doesn't mention the `assigned` field at all, which is what you must do in order to say that
for each person and the task assigned to them, the person has all the skills required by the task. What you wrote means that for every task, every person has all the skills required by that task.  The only way to satisfy that, is if all tasks have the same set of skills, which is exactly what you noticed in all instances you were getting for your model.

Here is how I would model this (note the slight changes in field and signature names, which makes the model slightly more readable and understandable):

```
some sig Skill {}

some sig Person  {
    hasSkill:  some Skill, 
    assignedTask: lone Task
}

some sig Task {  
    requiredSkills: some Skill
}

// everyone must have the required skills for the assigned task
fact requiredTaskSkills {
    all p:Person | p.hasSkill in p.assignedTask.requiredSkills
}

// everyone has at least one assigned task
pred atLeastOneTask {
    all p: Person | one p.assignedTask
}

// no two persons can have the same task assigned 
pred uniqueTaskAssignments {
    no disj p1, p2: Person | p1.assignedTask = p2.assignedTask
}    

run { 
    atLeastOneTask and uniqueTaskAssignments
}
```

Comment: You sir, are my hero. Thank you so much. I had to flip `p.hasSkill in p.assignedTask.requiredSkills` though since otherwise just 1 skill within tasks required skill set became enough for it to be assigned.

Comment: That's exactly correct, it should be `p.assignedTask.requiredSkills in p.hasSkill`.  Sorry for that mistake